# Clarification of Terms around Haskell Type system

Tags: haskell, terminology

Type system in haskell seem to be very Important and I wanted to clarify some terms revolving around haskell type system.

1. Some type classes

   - `Functor`
   - `Applicative`
   - `Monad`

   After using `:info` I found that `Functor` is a type class, `Applicative` is a type class with `=>` (deriving?) `Functor` and `Monad` deriving `Applicative` type class.

   I've read that `Maybe` is a Monad, does that mean `Maybe` is also `Applicative` and `Functor`?
2. `->` operator

   When i define a type

   ```
   data Maybe = Just a | Nothing
   ```

   and check `:t Just` I get `Just :: a -> Maybe a`. How to read this `->` operator?

   It confuses me with the function where `a -> b` means it evaluates `a` to `b` (sort of returns a maybe) – I tend to think lhs to rhs association but it turns when defining types?
3. The term type is used in ambiguous ways, Type, Type Class, Type Constructor, Concrete Type  etc... I would like to know what they mean to be exact

Comment: I think these are multiple questions. Question 1 is a bit too vague in my opinion. Questions 2 and 3 would make good questions, but I think it is better to open two separate stack overflow questions for them.

Comment: I think it might be better to follow a tutorial like [LYAH](learnyouahaskell.com/) that will *gradually* the concepts like type, type class, type constructor, etc. In my humble opinion that usually also means that you see the how these concepts work (together).

Comment: @Noughtmare I'm removing Q1 respecting your opinion, It's quite difficult to comprehend the concepts as a beginner as terms that specify type are so distributed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm following that book, and Got stuck with these concepts. I'll go through it again after getter a different prespective on these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed the word “type” is used in somewhat ambiguous ways.

The perhaps most practical way to look at it is that a **type** is just a *set of values*. For example, `Bool` is the finite set containing the values `True` and `False`.
Mathematically, there are subtle differences between the concepts of *set* and *type*, but they aren't really important for a programmer to worry about. But you should in general consider the sets to be infinite, for example `Integer` contains arbitrarily big numbers.

The most obvious way to define a type is with a `data` declaration, which in the simplest case just lists all the values:

```
data Colour = Red | Green | Blue
```

There we have a type which, as a set, contains three values.

**Concrete type** is basically what we say to make it clear that we mean the above: a particular type that corresponds to a set of values. `Bool` is a concrete type, that can easily be understood as a `data` definition, but also `String`, `Maybe Integer` and `Double -> IO String` are concrete types, though they don't correspond to any single `data` declaration.

What a *concrete type* can't have is *type variables*<sup>†</sup>, nor can it be an incompletely applied type constructor. For example, `Maybe` is not a concrete type.

So what is a **type constructor**? It's the type-level analogue to value constructors. What we mean mathematically by “constructor” in Haskell is an [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), i.e. a function *f* where if you're given *f*(*x*) you can clearly identify what was *x*. Furthermore, any different constructors are assumed to have disjoint ranges, which means you can also identify *f*.<sup>‡</sup>

`Just` is an example of a value constructor, but it complicates the discussion that it also has a type parameter. Let's consider a simplified version:

```
data MaybeInt = JustI Int | NothingI
```

Now we have

```
JustI :: Int -> MaybeInt
```

That's how `JustI` is a *function*. Like any function of the same signature, it can be applied to argument values of the right type, like, you can write `JustI 5`.
What it means for this function to be injective is that I can define a variable, say,

```
quoxy :: MaybeInt
quoxy = JustI 9328
```

and then I can *pattern match* with the `JustI` constructor:

```
> case quoxy of { JustI n -> print n }
9328
```

This would not be possible with a general function of the same signature:

```
foo :: Int -> MaybeInt
foo i = JustI $ negate i


> case quoxy of { foo n -> print n }
<interactive>:5:17: error: Parse error in pattern: foo
```

Note that constructors can be *nullary*, in which case the injective property is meaningless because there is no contained data / arguments of the injective function. `Nothing` and `True` are examples of nullary constructors.

Type constructors are the same idea as value constructors: *type-level functions* that can be pattern-matched. Any type-name defined with `data` is a type constructor, for example `Bool`, `Colour` and `Maybe` are all type constructors. `Bool` and `Colour` are nullary, but `Maybe` is a unary type constructor: it takes a type argument and only the result is then a concrete type.

So unlike value-level functions, type-level functions are kind of by default type constructors. There are also type-level functions that aren't constructors, but they require `-XTypeFamilies`.

A **type class** may be understood as a *set of types*, in the same vein as a type can be seen as a set of values. This is not quite accurate, it's closer to true to say a class is *a set of type constructors* but again it's not as useful to ponder the mathematical details – better to look at examples.

There are two main differences between type-as-set-of-values and class-as-set-of-types:

- How you define the “elements”: when writing a `data` declaration, you need to immediately describe what values are allowed. By contrast, a `class` is defined “empty”, and then the **instances** are defined later on, possibly in a different module.
- How the elements are *used*. A `data` type basically enumerates all the values so they can be *identified* again. Classes meanwhile aren't generally concerned with identifying types, rather they specify *properties* that the element-types fulfill. These properties come in the form of *methods* of a class. For example, the instances of the `Num` class are types that have the property that you can add elements together.

You could say, Haskell is statically typed on the value level (fixed sets of values in each type), but duck-typed on the type level (classes just require that somebody somewhere implements the necessary methods).

A simplified version of the `Num` example:

```
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a

instance Num Int where
  0 + x = x
  x + y = ...
```

If the `+` operator weren't already defined in the prelude, you would now be able to use it with `Int` numbers. Then later on, perhaps in a different module, you could also make it usable with new, custom number types:

```
data MyNumberType = BinDigits [Bool]

instance Num MyNumberType where
  BinDigits [] + BinDigits l = BinDigits l
  BinDigits (False:ds) + BinDigits (False:es)
    = BinDigits (False : ...)
```

Unlike `Num`, **the `Functor`...`Monad` type classes** are not classes of types, but of 1-ary type constructors. I.e. every functor is a type constructor taking one argument to make it a concrete type. For instance, recall that `Maybe` is a 1-ary type constructor.

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a->b) -> f a -> f b

instance Functor Maybe where
  fmap f (Just a) = Just (f a)
  fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
```

As you have concluded yourself, `Applicative` is a **subclass** of `Functor`. *D* being a subclass of *C* means basically that *D* is a subset of the set of type constructors in *C*. Therefore, yes, if `Maybe` is an instance of `Monad` it also is an instance of `Functor`.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>That's not quite true: if you consider the _universal quantor_ explicitly as part of the type, then a concrete type can contain variables. This is a bit of an advanced subject though.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>This is not guaranteed to be true if the `-XPatternSynonyms` extension is used.</sub>

Comment: Can you address the subtle(?) distinction between, say, `Either` and `Either Int`? (I believe the former is a type constructor, while the latter is just an expression that  produces a value of type `Type -> Type`?)

Comment: Good point. `Either Int` is still an injective type-level function, but would probably not be called type constructor. Maybe it should be though – it can be used basically like a type constructor.

Comment: Ok so bool, Color are nullary constructor And a concrete type ? So, nullary constructor would be concrete type ?

Comment: @AdharshM any nullary type constructor gives you directly a concrete type, yes. But an _n_ -ary type constructor applied to _n_ concrete types is also again a concrete type.